# Composer ErrorException when installing libraries

Tags: php, laravel, stream, composer-php, pyrocms

I'm working on installing a codebase from github (which is still in Pre-release stages). I am able to clone, from GitHub, to my working WAMP server. When I try to run "composer install" it eventually runs into an exception and I'm not entirely sure how to fix it? Am I missing local libraries in PEAR / php?

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mb_strto
lower' not found or invalid function name' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\streams\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support
\Pluralizer.php:258
```

**The exception as a gist with stack trace and more:**
https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/386be4c492dc16b8b43f

Any help / comments / advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install / enable the **mbstring** extension.

Further information can be found on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php)

Comment: I believe this did it. Thanks.